# How to change the data within elements in a XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I'm kind of new to XML files in C# ASP.NET. I have a XML in the below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Installation>
  <ServerIP>192.168.20.110</ServerIP>
  <DB_Name>USTCKT1</DB_Name>
  <Username>jorame</Username>
  <Password>Cru$%e20</Password>
  <Table_PreFix>TCK</Table_PreFix>
</Installation>
```

I need to change the values within each element. For example, when an user clicks I should be able to replace 192.168.20.110 with 192.168.1.12.

How can I accomplish this? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can do it in the following steps:

1. Create a new XmlDocument object and load the content. The content might be a file or string.
2. Find the element that you want to modify. If the structure of your xml file is too complex, you can use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) you find what you want.
3. Apply your modification to that element.
4. Update your xml file.

Here is a simple demo:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("file.xml"); // use LoadXml(string xml) to load xml string
    string path = "/Installation/ServerIP";
    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(path); // use xpath to find a node
    node.InnerText = "192.168.1.12"; // update node, replace the inner text
    xmlDoc.Save("file.xml"); // save updated content
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Would you mind showing how would you read what's inside the node?

Comment: @jorame My pleasure. XmlNode has many useful properties for you.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode_properties.aspx) Let's take "ServerIP" as an example. node.InnerText will return "192.168.1.12", if you have an attribute in the node, you can use node.Attributes["attributeName"] to get this attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I was able to accomplish the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using the XDocument class:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file.xml);
doc.Element("Installation").Element("ServerIP").Value = "192.168.1.12";
//Update the rest of the elements
doc.Save(file.xml);
```

[More Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387052.aspx)

If you run into namespace issues when selecting your elements you will need to include the xml namespace in the XElement selectors eg `doc.Element(namspace + "Installation")`

Comment: Would this replace the current value?

Comment: @jorame yes it will. The save will overwrite the xml in the XDocument

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using the methods in the XDocument class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301598.aspx

Specifically look at the methods: Load(string) - to load an XML file, Element() - to access a specific element and Save(string) - to save the XML document. The page on Element() has some sample code which can help.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx